# Integrate Millennial Media SDK 5.0 in Android Application

Tags: android, millennial-media

Regarding formatting the question, I tried to format it, but it doesn't show up few lines of code, I don't know why. It's happening for the second time today. Please if someone can format it, It would be great.

Quesiton -:

Android 2.3.3

I am just trying to integrate millennial media sdk into a demo app. No fancy stuff. Just simple app, to get an idea of implementing it.

Here is what I have done :::

1. Downloaded android_5_0_0_sdk from the site.
2. Created a project and added the MMSDK.jar file to libs
3. Rgight click on the project, go to properties->java build path->libraries->add jars-> chose  the path to the libs and MMSDK.jar

4.Added the XML code to my activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mm="http://millennialmedia.com/android/schema" // this
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    // and this
    <com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="468dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        mm:apid="123149"
        mm:height="60"
        mm:width="468" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

1. This is my AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.millennialdemo"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   <application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
       android:name="com.example.millennialdemo.MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

   <!-- Start of MillennialMedia.com code -->
   <activity
       android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" >
   </activity>
   <activity
       android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer"
       android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" >
   </activity>

   <!-- End of MillennialMedia.com code -->
   ```

1. Here is my  MainActivity:-

   ```
   import com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView;
   import com.millennialmedia.android.MMInterstitial;
   import com.millennialmedia.android.MMAd;
   import com.millennialmedia.android.MMBroadcastReceiver;
   import com.millennialmedia.android.MMRequest;
   import com.millennialmedia.android.MMSDK;
   import com.millennialmedia.android.RequestListener.RequestListenerImpl;
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       MMSDK.initialize(this);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       MMAdView adView = new MMAdView(this);

       //Replace YOUR_APID with the APID provided to you by Millennial Media
       adView.setApid("123149");

       //Set your metadata in the MMRequest object
       MMRequest request = new MMRequest();

       //Add metadata here.

       //Add the MMRequest object to your MMAdView.
       adView.setMMRequest(request);

       //Sets the id to preserve your ad on configuration changes.
       adView.setId(MMSDK.getDefaultAdId());
           adView.getAd();//change suggested by Millennial Mark


   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   }
   ```

I think I have done whatever is told in the document but i don't get any ad and all i get is the following log in my logcat...

```
05-20 20:54:58.932: E/Web Console(386): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
05-20 20:54:58.932: E/Web Console(386): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
05-20 20:54:58.972: W/MillennialMediaSDK(386): AdView onLayout changedfalse int left 24 int top 24 int right 456 int bottom 99
05-20 20:55:00.382: D/dalvikvm(386): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1228K, 57% free 2903K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 6ms+6ms
05-20 20:55:01.172: E/MillennialMediaSDK(386): Could not get a handshake. No peer certificate
05-20 20:55:01.172: E/MillennialMediaSDK(386): Could not get a handshake. No peer certificate
05-20 20:55:01.212: D/dalvikvm(386): GC_CONCURRENT freed 826K, 58% free 2843K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 6ms+5ms
```

I don't understand what's going wrong. If someone can help me, it's much appreciated.

After changing this

```
 MMAdView adView = new MMAdView(this);
```

to

```
MMAdView adView = (MMAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

I still have the same problem.. here is the logcat..

```
05-20 21:57:26.911: I/MillennialMediaSDK(467): Initializing MMLayout.
05-20 21:57:27.631: W/MillennialMediaSDK(467): MMLayout adding view (MMWebView originally from(1) MRaidState(loading).) to AdType[(b) InternalId(1) LinkedId(0) isFinishing(false)]
05-20 21:57:27.842: W/MillennialMediaSDK(467): AdView onLayout changedtrue int left 24 int top 24 int right 456 int bottom 114
05-20 21:57:27.861: W/MillennialMediaSDK(467): Id check for parent: 1 versus 1
05-20 21:57:27.911: W/MillennialMediaSDK(467): AdView onLayout changedfalse int left 24 int top 24 int right 456 int bottom 114
05-20 21:57:28.041: E/Web Console(467): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
05-20 21:57:28.051: E/Web Console(467): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
05-20 21:57:28.551: W/MillennialMediaSDK(467): AdView onLayout changedfalse int left 24 int top 24 int right 456 int bottom 114
05-20 21:57:29.541: D/dalvikvm(467): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1226K, 57% free 2905K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 5ms+9ms
05-20 21:57:30.292: E/MillennialMediaSDK(467): Could not get a handshake. No peer certificate
05-20 21:57:30.301: E/MillennialMediaSDK(467): Could not get a handshake. No peer certificate
05-20 21:57:30.331: D/dalvikvm(467): GC_CONCURRENT freed 813K, 58% free 2843K/6727K, external 2002K/2137K, paused 4ms+4ms
```

After changing the code as suggested by Millennial Mark, I get the following errors, basically the same..

```
05-21 08:54:38.948: I/MillennialMediaSDK(341): Initializing MMLayout.
05-21 08:54:39.616: W/MillennialMediaSDK(341): MMLayout adding view (MMWebView originally from(1) MRaidState(loading).) to AdType[(b) InternalId(1) LinkedId(0) isFinishing(false)]
05-21 08:54:40.027: W/MillennialMediaSDK(341): AdView onLayout changedtrue int left 24 int top 24 int right 456 int bottom 99
05-21 08:54:40.055: W/MillennialMediaSDK(341): Id check for parent: 1 versus 1
05-21 08:54:40.115: W/MillennialMediaSDK(341): AdView onLayout changedfalse int left 24 int top 24 int right 456 int bottom 99
05-21 08:54:40.295: E/Web Console(341): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
05-21 08:54:40.295: E/Web Console(341): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
05-21 08:54:40.295: W/MillennialMediaSDK(341): AdView onLayout changedfalse int left 24 int top 24 int right 456 int bottom 99
05-21 08:54:58.139: E/MillennialMediaSDK(341): Ad request HTTP error. androidsdk.ads.mp.mydas.mobi
05-21 08:54:59.527: E/MillennialMediaSDK(341): Could not get a handshake. ads.mp.mydas.mobi
05-21 08:54:59.527: E/MillennialMediaSDK(341): Could not get a handshake. ads.mp.mydas.mobi
```

I have went through the answers given by Millennial Mark in other scenarios. Here is what I have done.

Rightclick on project->properties->java build path->go to order and export tab and check the checkbox of the MMSDK jar file. Now, I don't get the "handshake" error, but the "reference" error still comes up and NO AD is being displayed as well.

Here is the logcat trace

```
05-21 09:03:33.565: E/Web Console(341): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
05-21 09:03:46.296: W/MillennialMediaSDK(341): Id check for parent: 1 versus 1
05-21 09:03:46.346: E/Web Console(341): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MMJS at undefined:1
```

Modified MainActivity

```
package com.example.millennialdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView;
import com.millennialmedia.android.MMInterstitial;
import com.millennialmedia.android.MMAd;
import com.millennialmedia.android.MMBroadcastReceiver;
import com.millennialmedia.android.MMRequest;
import com.millennialmedia.android.MMSDK;
import com.millennialmedia.android.RequestListener.RequestListenerImpl;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MMSDK.initialize(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MMAdView adView = (MMAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        //Replace YOUR_APID with the APID provided to you by Millennial Media
        adView.setApid("123149");

        //Set your metadata in the MMRequest object
        MMRequest request = new MMRequest();

        //Add metadata here.

        //Add the MMRequest object to your MMAdView.
        adView.setMMRequest(request);

        //Sets the id to preserve your ad on configuration changes.
        adView.setId(MMSDK.getDefaultAdId());
        adView.getAd();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Tarun was right in his first step. Change:

`MMAdView adView = new MMAdView(this);`

to

`MMAdView adView = (MMAdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);`

and add:

`adView.getAd();`

...at the end of your Activity's onCreate(...) method ( after `adView.setId(MMSDK.getDefaultAdId());` ).

Comment: I have changed the code as suggested by you, I still get the same error. I have updated my question with the error, please have a look and guide me.

Comment: I could get rid of "handshake" error, but the "reference" error still exists. Please look at the updated question.

Comment: I think the `MMAdView adView = (MMAdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);` is still missing-- it's what is still giving you grief. My working implementation (which a modification of your code here) has the Reference error, too, but the ad view appears. I think when you call MMAdView = new MMAdView(this), you're creating a new MMAdView and calling getAd on it, but it's not displaying an ad because this isn't the object referenced in your XML layout file.

Comment: I have done that before itself. I have updated my question with the modified code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I get the ad displayed. I have been using the emulator for running the code. When I run it on my mobile, i can see the ad.

Comment: As long as you see the ad, there's no problem. The other "errors" you see are debug output and won't affect your performance.

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`MMAdView adView = new MMAdView(this);`

to

`MMAdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);`

Comment: `android:layout_width="468dp"
 android:layout_height="60dp" mm:height="60"
        mm:width="468"` change the dimensions to 320x50 and try.